# Почему submodule переключается на HEAD после update?

Tags: git

Мой гит репо использует `submodule` и когда я стягиваю изменения в своем основном репо я так же в терминале делаю эту команду

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

и когда я открываю свой `submodule` я вижу, что вместо того, чтоб быть на `dev` ветке он почему то переключается на `HEAD` которая имеет поинтер на пару недель назад, то есть не обновленная и я как бы руками опять ее переключаю на `dev` (и HEAD при этом исчезает)

В общем я не совсем пойму, я ожидаю, что при вызове команды `update --recursive` все сабмодули должны подтянуть последние изменения веток на которых они стоят, то есть если в сабмодуле активная ветка сейчас `dev` то он должен подтянуть все последние изменения с дев, а не создавать HEAD которые еще и не обновленный...

что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что делаю не так?

Вот это:

> я ожидаю, что при вызове команды update --recursive все сабмодули
> должны подтянуть последние изменения веток на которых они стоят

К сожалению, это так не работает - `update` затянет те коммиты, хэши которых сохранены в корневом репозитории.

К счастью, есть дополнительные ключи, которые заставят `git` делать то, что вы хотите:

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

Comment: я так понимаю, что гит сохраняет хэши в корневом репо для того, чтоб не было проблем когда переключаешься с ветки на ветку в руте? Ну я имею ввиду, что допустим у меня есть рут дев1 и дев2 ветки но сабмодули дев1 уже ушли вперед по разработке а история сабмодулей дев2  не обновлялась и получается, что кода я переключаюсь между дев1 и дев2 в руте, то он автоматически переключает саб модули на релевантные комиты, чтоб не получилось так что я переключил ветку в рут но код сабмодуля уже изменен, или не так я понимаю?

Comment: Да. Это делается для того, чтобы коммиты в корневом репо были консистентны с коммитами в сабмодулях

Comment: то есть если подумать, то после запуска этой команды я могу получить последние апдейты на сабмодули, которые в итоге не будет консистентны с моей рут веткой, верно?

Comment: Если подумать, то да.